# Программы по синхронизации с файлами на сервере

Tags: linux, администрирование, svn

Нужна программа со следующим функционалом:

Есть сервер в сети, на котором хранятся общие файлы, нескольких пользователей. С ним установлено соединение сразу несколькими юзерами. Общие файлы периодически синхронизируются с файлами на сервере.

Просто указываешь папку где находятся файлы с сервера, и они их синхронизирует (докачивает, заменяет, обновляет)

В общем: Что-то в духе Subversion (SVN).

В общем, кто сталкивался, посоветуйте. Желательно кросплатфоремнную.
Предполагается что серверная часть будет на линуксе. Клиенты различных ОС.

В ответе указать конкретную программу, преимущества.

Comment: Чем плох расшареный диск или тот же SVN?

Comment: все гениальное просто, зачем усложнять ситуацию?
можете обьяснить какой функционал вам нужен которого нет в CVS/SVN ?

Comment: Видимо тем, что ему не нужно хранить историю изменений. Ему нужно синхронизировать папки и все.

Answer (score 3):

rsync ?

Comment: Одна беда, в вопросе "Клиенты различных ОС".

Comment: Использовать порты rsync под различные ОС.

Comment: Вот тут: [HOWTO build your own open source Dropbox clone](http://fak3r.com/geek/howto-build-your-own-open-source-dropbox-clone/) - **как построить свой dropbox с ...** на основе rsync.